# Editing and viewing Cookies

Tags: cookies, google-chrome

everyone! I wish to view and edit the  cookies of my google chrome. Tell me a way to do it.
Thanx in advance.

Comment: I don't believe this belongs on StackOverflow. Try [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/)

Comment: Right, this could probably be moved to http://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4):

Tools -> Developer Tools -> Resources -> Cookies. Can't edit the cookies form here though.

Answer (score 1):

[CookieSpy](http://www.cookiespy.com) is a free tool to view internet cookes of different web browsers. It shows chrome cookies as well.

Answer (score -1):

Options > Under the Hood > Content settings... > Cookies > Show cookies and other site data.

Comment: Doesn't let you edit it, though.